# How to search a particular string and content in a yaml file

Tags: python, python-2.7, yaml

Here below is my yaml file

```
    filename:
      #Name of the JMX files which needs to be executed
      - URLLogin.txt
      - URLupload.txt
      - XlsxFileUpload.txt

    URLLogin:
      - this is to test the script

    XlsxFileUpload:
      - this is to test the current script
```

I will be storing the filenames in an array. and call a method to get the file description in a loop. If the description is present for the filename it should return 1, else it should return zero

Here below is my code for searching the description.

```
#this method is to search a particular string in yaml
def searchStringInYaml(filename,string):
    with open(filename, 'r') as stream:
        content = yaml.load(stream)
        if string in content:
            print string
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
    stream.close()
```

Comment: `yaml.load` returns a dictionary. The colons are not kept

Comment: okay. If I remove colon also I am not able to search the string. It is returning only zero always @cricket_007

Comment: `string in content` only checks the keys of the dictionary, not any values

Comment: how to check the values then? @cricket_007

Comment: It's not clear what you're searching for. Do you absolutely need to parse the yaml, or do you only need to check if the file contains `string`? If the later, then you can `return 1 if string in open(filename).read() else 0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`yaml.load(stream)` returns a dict use `content.items()` to iterate and check for value

**Ex:**

```
import yaml
with open(filename, 'r') as stream:
    content = yaml.load(stream)
    for k,v in content.items():
        if "URLLogin.txt" in v:
            print k, v
```

**Output:**

```
filename ['URLLogin.txt', 'URLupload.txt', 'XlsxFileUpload.txt']
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is to check for a specified string in yaml file, dont parse the yaml file. Just read the file and check the contents

```
def searchStringInYaml(filename,string):
    with open(filename) as f:
        contents = f.read()
        return string in contents
```